# PageSetup.Zoom issues not updating page break

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.zoom = 80
```

If i reset all page break then use this code above to change my scale, it does not adjust the automatic page breaks. If I manually go into Page Setup under the File menu, the scale has been adjusted to 80%. If I press OK then the page breaks will automatically change. How do I get the page breaks to update in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Page View with `ActiveWindow.View`.

**e.g:**

```
Sub Zoom()

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 80
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not setting the window's zoom, i'm setting the Scale to Fit zoom.

Comment: My fault, I edited the answer.  Is that what you meant to do ?

Comment: It's still not shifting my page breaks as if i was to do it manually. You would think that if you set the PageSetup.Zoom it would shift it down since 80 is smaller than 100 and so and so. If i did a manual print preview the page breaks will move to where its suppose to go.